# pandas read_csv with multiple separators does not work

Tags: pandas, csv

I need to be able to parse 2 different types of CSVs with `read_csv`, the first has `;`-separated values and the second has `,`-separated values. I need to do this at the same time.

That is, the CSV can have this format:

```
some;csv;values;here
```

or this:

```
some,csv,values,here
```

or even mixed:

```
some;csv,values;here
```

I tried many things like the following regex but nothing worked:

```
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=r'[,;]', engine='python')
```

Am I doing something wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading from a file, I ran your code sample
reading from a string:

```
txt = '''C1;C2,C3;C4
some;csv,values;here
some1;csv1,values1;here1'''
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep='[,;]', engine='python')
```

and got a **proper** result:

```
      C1    C2       C3     C4
0   some   csv   values   here
1  some1  csv1  values1  here1
```

Note that the *sep* parameter can be even an **ordinary** (not *raw*) string,
because it does not contain any backslashes.

So your idea to specify multiple separators as a regex pattern is OK.

The reason that your code failed is probably an "inconsistent" division of
lines into fileds. Maybe you should ensure that each line contains **the
same number** of commas and semi-colons (at least not too many).

Look thoroughly at your stack trace. There should include some information
about which line of the source file caused the problem.
Then look at the indicated line and correct it.

## Edit

To look what happens in a "failure case", I changed the source string to:

```
txt = '''C1;C2,C3;C4
some;csv,values;here
some1;csv1,values1;here1
some2;csv2,values2;here2,xxxx'''
```

i.e. I added one line with **5** fields (one too many).

Then execution of the above code results in an error message:

```
ParserError: Expected 4 fields in line 4, saw 5. ...
```

Note words *in line 4*, precisely indicating the offending input line
(line numbers starts from 1).